# Getting current RGB color of Image

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, alpha

I want to change the Alpha color of `image(script)` component of `GameObject`.

But saving the RGB values of the object.

I tried the next code:

```
        targetObject.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color32(
            (byte)targetObject.GetComponent<Image>().color.r,
            (byte)targetObject.GetComponent<Image>().color.g,
            (byte)targetObject.GetComponent<Image>().color.b, 
            toAlpha);
```

But `(byte)targetObject.GetComponent<Image>().color.r` returns 0 what so ever.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you mean after you have executed this code?

Comment: @adjan of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The struct `Color` uses channel values in the range [0,1]. So, white is (1,1,1,1) and black (0,0,0,0). The `color` propriety returns a `Color` struct, not a `Color32`.

When you cast `float` to `byte`, the result will be 1 if the channel is at 1, or 0 if is less than 1. Since you're using these values in a `Color32` struct (which uses an `int` per channel in the range [0,255]), if the starting color is full white, you'll have an almost black of (1,1,1,1), if any channel isn't full on (i.e. <255 using ints), the channel will be full off.

Just change `new Color32` to `new Color` and remove the `(byte)` cast.